# How to import a js file to another js in html project

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I am working on a html project. I have 2 js file like `main.js` and `config.js`. I have some default export in `config.js`. So I was using import statement in `main.js` while it is giving me error **Cannot use import outside of a module**. Is there anyway to import `config.js` inside `main.js`?

**config.js file**

```
export const config = {
    identityBaseURL : 'https://url1.azurewebsites.net/',
    tenantId : '1234',
}
```

the above code is my config that I exported from `config.js` and wanted to import in `main.js`

```
import config from './config.js';
```

The above line I am using to import my config file into `main.js` file but I am getting the error which is **Cannot use import outside of a module**.

Comment: How is the JS being used in the HTML file?

Comment: I have linked the main.js in the HTML file

Comment: Please may you edit the question to show us how?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, can you please ask your question clearly? I really did not understand your question

Comment: The error being given is telling you that the javascript is being used outside of a module. Please edit the question you've written to include a [mcve] of the javascript being used inside the HTML file. Please also read the link provided by Quentin.

Comment: So there are 2 ways one is use bable to change it into safe JS, or learn how to use modules https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules